# How to get JSON object values with the JSON keys having spaces in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This is my JSON object :

```
var EVENT_ID = {
  "Enable Popup Blocker": "Sol_EnablePopupBlocker_IE",
  "Disable Script Debug": "Sol_DisableScriptDebugger_IE",
  "Clear History": "Sol_ClearHistory_IE",
  "Reset Settings": "Reset_InternetExplorer_Settings_SA",
  "Profile Issue": "Fix_Outlook_Profile_SA",
  "Send Receive": "Fix_Send_Receive_Errors_Outlook_SA",
  "Search Issue": "Fix_Search_Outlook_SA"
};
```

I am trying to access the JSON object value with keys, which has spaces as shown below

```
var eventID = JSON.stringify(req.body.result.parameters.solution); 
var aptEventName = EVENT_ID[eventID];
```

`eventID` value is `"Profile Issue"`

When I log my `aptEventName` variable, it throws values as `undefined`. Can anyone please tell me, where I am going wrong?

Comment: can you post what do you get in **req.body.result.parameters.solution** ?

Comment: this is  my request .body .result structure   {
 "source": "agent",
 "resolvedQuery": "LPTP-KDUSHYANT",
 "speech": "",
 "action": "gethostname",
 "actionIncomplete": false,
 "parameters": {
  "solution": "Profile Issue",
  "hostname": "LPTP-KDUSHYANT"
 }    For req.body.result.parameters.solution i am getting Profile Issue

Comment: try this once `EVENT_ID[req.body.result.parameters.solution]`

Comment: still it throws me undefined error

Comment: @Arulvelu but it is working fine when I'm testing it here. **Run the snippet** here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51160168/3723368

Comment: Thank you people. It worked.. I had problem with the key which i passed. Thanks a ton for your valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

**ONE POSSIBLE CASE:** when you again do `JSON.stringify()` on a string value this could happen. That's why **it throws values as undefined**, so don't use unnecessary `JSON.stringify()` here

```
var response = "response"
JSON.stringify(response)
""response"" 
^^        ^^ see extra quotes here
```

```js
var result = { "source": "agent", "resolvedQuery": "LPTP-KDUSHYANT", "speech": "", "action": "gethostname", "actionIncomplete": false, "parameters": { "solution": "Profile Issue", "hostname": "LPTP-KDUSHYANT" }}
var eventID = result.parameters.solution;
var EVENT_ID = {
  "Enable Popup Blocker": "Sol_EnablePopupBlocker_IE",
  "Disable Script Debug": "Sol_DisableScriptDebugger_IE",
  "Clear History": "Sol_ClearHistory_IE",
  "Reset Settings": "Reset_InternetExplorer_Settings_SA",
  "Profile Issue": "Fix_Outlook_Profile_SA",
  "Send Receive": "Fix_Send_Receive_Errors_Outlook_SA",
  "Search Issue": "Fix_Search_Outlook_SA"
};

var aptEventName = EVENT_ID[eventID];
console.log(aptEventName)
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` called on a string will return the string in quotes. You should not JSON-encode your key. And as string typecast is implicit when performing object field access you can type it just as:

```
var eventID = req.body.result.parameters.solution;
var aptEventName = EVENT_ID[eventID];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using stringify, it is taking a string and turning that string into JSON.

```
var eventID =  JSON.stringify(req.body.result.parameters.solution);
```

when you do this your string is going to be

```
var eventID = "\"Profile Issue\"";
```

So of course you have no properties in your object with quotes. So what you need to do is drop the stringify bit and just have to reference the property in your object.

```
var eventID = req.body.result.parameters.solution;
var aptEventName = EVENT_ID[eventID];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values using:

```
EVENT_ID["Clear History"]
```

I think you have something wroong with the
`req.body.result.parameters.solution`.

Comment: It throws me undefined

Comment: Can you post what do you get in **req.body.result.parameters.solution**??